# DatePicker submit the previous date and when clear date submit `1970-01-01`

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) works good.

I have only 2 problems with this component.

First: When I clear DatePicker and click submit, saved data `1970-01-01`. How to remove it? I want to submit empty date when I clear input.

Second: I put today date 8/2/2019, in submit save the previous date 8/1/2019

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnjeew-1nmjex?file=app/datepicker-color-example.ts)

Comment: can you send edit version of stackblits

Comment: Ups sorry https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnjeew-1nmjex?file=app/datepicker-color-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you're clearing the date, value is getting changed to null and you're not handling the null in your model constructor.
2. As you're converting date into ISOstring which will be 8:30 hours back. So you're getting one day back in selected date.

Add following in your `MyModel.ts` file

```
 export class MyModel {
fromdate: number;
todate: number;


  constructor(obj: any) {
    console.log();
      this.fromdate = obj.fromdate === null ? '' : obj && <any>(new Date(obj.fromdate)) !== "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(<any>new Date(obj.fromdate)) ? new Date(new Date(obj.fromdate).setDate(new Date(obj.fromdate).getDate()+1)).toISOString().slice(0, 10) : obj.fromdate || obj.fromdate || '';
  this.todate = obj.todate === null ? '' : obj && <any>(new Date(obj.todate)) !== "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(<any>new Date(obj.todate)) ? new Date(new Date(obj.todate).setDate(new Date(obj.todate).getDate()+1)).toISOString().slice(0, 10) : obj.todate || obj.todate || '';
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any different from my model. Can you edit my demo please?

Comment: There is issue in stackblitz to share. Replace your `MyModel.ts` constructor with above code which will solve your first issue.

Comment: I updated my answer which will solve both your issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular builtin method `formatDate()` to format the date.

1). import the formatDate() from common module.

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

2).just use format method to get formatted date.

```
formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en');
```

As per angular document formatDate() used to Formats a date according to locale rules.

```
formatDate(value: string | number | Date, format: string, locale: string, timezone?: string): string
```

And it will returns string: The formatted date string.